# How can I parse a paginated REST API as a teiid datasource?

Tags: java, teiid

For my job I have to expose an API that will be able to gather data from multiple datasources. That's why I have to implement some data virtualization using teiid: as I am alone on this project, designing all the classes to match every json object would be a waste of time.

It appears that some of my datasources are paginated REST Api. I know that teiid can handle REST Api's easily, but what about those that are paginated?

The response is something like:

```
{
  "total": 132,
  "subtotal": 132,
  "page": 2,
  "per_page": 100,
  "search": null,
  "sort": {
    "by": null,
    "order": null
  },
  "results": [ ... ]
}
```

I already have a java class that can parse the whole API by using a do..while loop that looks like this:

```
page = 1;
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
do {
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> request = template.exchange(url+endpoint+"?page=" + page, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SatelliteResponseJSON response;
    try {
        response = mapper.readValue(request.getBody().getBytes(), SatelliteResponseJSON.class);
        total = response.getTotal();
        parsed += response.getPer_page();
        page += 1;
        result.addAll(response.getResults());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }while (parsed < total);
```

Is there any means to make the same kind of thing for my VDB, so I don't have to write a java class for each kind of object I would work to? If not, how could I avoid writing such classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in support currently, as the paging on REST API would be custom per given source, and it would be difficult to figure out "nextURL" for the next page from given original one.

But, you should be able to extend the "ws" translator in Teiid code and provide that functionality easily, especially if all of your sources follow same paging structure. If you can think of this feature generically and have ideas I would not mind accepting as a contribution or developing this collaboratively.

BTW, OData translator we support does have paging feature, if your sources were OData this would work seamlessly. You can take a look at that as an example, but not really required.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ramesh, but I think I will just do some scripting to parse the API and then put the results into a single file that teiid will parse (or whatever other solution). Maybe I'll check that translator later but as you said, as rest pagination is not standardized yet it would be difficult to build a generic ws translator.